# Error in importing Bond Framework in iOS app

Tags: ios

I hope anyone can help me with my problem. I'm trying to use Dynamic UIImage in my program which is supported by Bond Framework. So, I am getting error (no such module 'Bond') while I am importing the Bond framework. I even installed the third party library cocoapods and I integrated with my project.yet I have same problem.

Here is a sample of my program code

import Foundation
import Parse
import Bond

// 1
class Post : PFObject, PFSubclassing {

```
var image: Dynamic<UIImage?> = Dynamic(nil) // dynamic image property 

var photoUploadTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?

// 2
@NSManaged var imageFile: PFFile?
@NSManaged var user: PFUser?


//MARK: PFSubclassing Protocol

// 3
static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Post"
}

// 4
override init () {
    super.init()
}

override class func initialize() {
    var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
        // inform Parse about this subclass
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow CocoaPods instructions? https://cocoapods.org/#get_started

Your Podfile should look similarly to this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyTargetName' do
  pod 'Bond', '~> 3.9'
end
```

Where `MyTargetName` is name of your target.

[image]

After you've configured your Podfile, run following command from the same directory:

```
pod install
```

Additionally, make sure you open YourApp.xcworkspace instead of YourApp.xcodeproj.

Comment: Thank you so much! you solved my problem. I think the issue was in my podfile content because it was look like pod 'AFNetworking'
  pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~>3.12'
  pod 'Bond'